# How to get an amount of open trades in MQL5

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

I want to get the amount of open trades in **`MQL5`** on a demo account during strategy testing.

`PositionsTotal()` and `OrdersTotal()` always return **`0`** even if there are open trades.

The solution suggested [here](https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/1995#comment_18270) does not work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: **Would you mind to add a few PrintScreens and source code**, to show exactly the colliding case ( having Orders in StrategyTester while having no such reported in OrdersTotal() )?

Comment: `PostionsTotal()` always gets the number of open positions just as `OrdersTotal()` gets the number of open pending orders, doesnt matter which client of `MetaTrader5` you are running. If you want more help you need to provide a code sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurred when running the code in the Metatrader 5 downloaded from Metaquotes' website. Running the same code in a Metatrader 5 instance from a forex broker resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

according to https://mql5tutorial.com/mql5-tutorial-how-to-simply-count-positions-with-mql5/, you can use the following code for doing this

```
void OnTick()

{

int PositionForThisCurrencyPair = 0;

for (int i = PositionsTotal()-1; i>=0; i--)
{
string symbol = PositionGetSymbol(i);

if(Symbol() == symbol)

{   

PositionForThisCurrencyPair+=1 ;

}
}

Comment("\n\n positions for this currency pair:",PositionForThisCurrencyPair);
}
```

Comment: but i always will be -1 and it will never get into de "for" . right?